# How do I fix my docker-compose.yml? - expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'

Tags: docker, yaml

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>' in "./docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 3
```

It seems there is an indentation issue in my yml file. I read some other questions on here, and tried various indentation schemes.  I still cannot get it to work.  I purposely removed the env names/pws before posting this question.

```
version: '2'
  ghost:
    image: ghost:latest
    container_name: ghost-blog  #Specify a custom container name, rather than a generated default name.
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db-name # Change {{db-name}}
      - MYSQL_USER=user # Change {{username}}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass # Change {{db-password}}
      # - "MAILGUN_USER={{mailgun-user}}" # Change {{mailgun-user}}
      # - "MAILGUN_PASSWORD={{mailgun-password}}" # Change {{mailgun-password}}
    volumes:
      - ./ghost:/var/lib/ghost # persist the data
    ports:
      - 2368:2368
    depends_on:
      - mysql # ensure that the database will start first
    restart: always

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: ghost-db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname # Change {{db-name}}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=db-pass # Change {{root-password}}
      - MYSQL_USER=user # Change {{username}}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=sq-pass # Change {{db-password}}
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
```

Comment: I think you are missing the services: tag like it has here
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-3-define-services-in-a-compose-file

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the future, you could use this [website](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) to check what is wrong with it and then fix it on the go.

**EDIT:**

So the problems you had with your docker-compose file were as follows:

1. You didn't added the *services:* keyword after the version and
2. You don't have to pass the *:latest* tag if you want the latest image, you will pass the tag when you want a specific version of the image and that's done between " "

---

As for the code, it should be as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
      ghost:
        image: ghost
        container_name: ghost-blog
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=production
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=db-name
          - MYSQL_USER=user
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
      #   - "MAILGUN_USER={{mailgun-user}}"
      #   - "MAILGUN_PASSWORD={{mailgun-password}}" # Change {{mailgun-password}}
        volumes:
         - ./ghost:/var/lib/ghost # persist the data
        ports:
          - 2368:2368
        depends_on:
          - mysql # ensure that the database will always start first
        restart: always
    
      mysql:
        image: mysql
        container_name: ghost-db
        environment:
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname # Change {{db-name}}
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=db-pass # Change {{root-password}}
          - MYSQL_USER=user # Change {{username}}
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=sq-pass # Change {{db-password}}
        volumes:
          - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
```

Comment: The code you posted does not pass the parser you recommended.

    ` 
ERROR:
    while parsing a block mapping
          in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 2:
            ghost:
            ^
        expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
          in "<unicode string>", line 21, column 3:
               mysql:
`

Comment: @JAstuccio I've edited my code. Please see the comments i've made

Comment: Thank you. It passes the parser, but I am still getting the same error when I copy your new code and change the passwords.

Comment: @JAstuccio yes, as i have tested it locally and no errors are thrown

Answer (score 13):

In my case, the error caused by lacking a space before service name(like mysql). Hope this information can help someone!

Comment: For me, it was an extra space

Comment: it was the same for, spaces and wrong use of quotes. You can verify the file on 
[Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) before running a container. That is what I do, after a big change.

Answer (score 3):

For me problem were with not enough indentation of the line.
I added a tab in line where problem occurs and next to further dependent from this one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra spacing that you have written:

and maintain proper indentation

[image]