# yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping line 1, column 1

Tags: docker-compose

I am building my first docker-compost.yml file, but can not seem to get the errors to clear when I run docker-compose config. I keep getting the following:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1 expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>' in "./docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 5
```

Below is the configuration of the .yml file. I am sure it is something really simple, but I have never done anything like this before. O if it means anything I am using Notepad++ to edit.

```
version: '3'
services:
googlehomekodi:
    image: omertu/googlehomekodi
    ports:
      - "8099:8099"
    environment:
      - KODI_PROTOCOL=http
      - KODI_IP=192.168.1.212
      - KODI_PORT=8080
      - KODI_USER=kodi
      - KODI_PASSWORD=kodi
      - AUTH_TOKEN=stuff
 restart: always
```

Comment: I was not able to post the error in the original. Here it is ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 5

Comment: you can check your yml on this webiste: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/
It seems that the identation in your  last line `restart: always` is incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix my docker-compose.yml? - expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769746/how-do-i-fix-my-docker-compose-yml-expected-block-end-but-found-block-ma)

Comment: What should the indentation be?  I tried taking out the spaces in front of restart, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: It should be at the same level `image: ...`

Comment: I got it working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is not correct in your compose file (`googlehomekodi:` should be under `services:` and `restart: always` should be under `googlehomekodi:`).

**The correct indentation:**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  googlehomekodi:
    image: omertu/googlehomekodi
    ports:
      - "8099:8099"
    environment:
      - KODI_PROTOCOL=http
      - KODI_IP=192.168.1.212
      - KODI_PORT=8080
      - KODI_USER=kodi
      - KODI_PASSWORD=kodi
      - AUTH_TOKEN=stuff
    restart: always
```